# Ember template not updating when new record is saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple template, whose route assigns a collection of price points as the model. In the template, I iterate through these and output the amounts:

```
{{#each pricePoint in controller}}
    li.bar-levels__value ${{pricePoint.amount}}
{{/each}}
```

In this same template there's a form to create a new PricePoint. It calls an action which is handled in the controller and creates and saves a record:

```
this.store.createRecord('pricePoint', {
    brandCode: property.get('brandCode'),
    propertyNumber: property.get('propertyNumber'),
    amount: parseFloat(this.newValue)
}).save();
```

This works correctly in that it saves the record via my REST API and on a page refresh I can verify that it appears in the list of pricePoints. But why doesn't the list update in real-time, ie. when I save the record successfully? It worked this way before I made the switch from a FixtureAdapter to a RESTAdapter...

Please help!

**EDIT 1:**
Here's my route:

```
App.PropertyPricingBarPricePointsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('pricePoint', { propertyId: params.propertyId })
    }
});
```

Comment: See if changing `controller` to `this` solves the problem. Otherwise please create a fiddle that recreates this problem.

Comment: What does the response look like? Does your endpoint output the updated model?

Comment: What's your route look like?

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi Changing `controller` to `this` didn't solve it. Creating a fiddle wouldn't really work since that would have to be based off of fixtures, and the issue was not present when working off of fixtures.